# How can I upgrade the *console* version of vim on OS X?

Tags: macos, vim, console

I'm sure this is a newbie question, but every time I've compiled/dl'ed a new version of vim for os x, running vim on the command-line opens up the gvim app. I just want to upgrade the console version (so I can, for example, have python compiled in to use omnicomplete).

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did you community wiki'ify the question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also use MacPorts to handle the installation for you. Once you've installed it,  run the `/opt/local/bin/vim` binary. I place this in my `PATH` before the system binary dirs (although be aware that this may cause problems for cmdline tools that rely on the versions of tools shipped with OS X).

Comment: it will be /opt/local/bin if you use a default installation of MacPorts

Answer (score 7):

If I understsood the question correcty, here is another solution: check out http://www.andrewvos.com/2011/07/23/upgrading-vim-on-os-x-with-homebrew/

Really simple, fast, painless.  It uses homebrew-alt and you also need to have mercurial installed (it will prompt you if not).

Answer (score 2):

This may sound stupid, but are you copying the vim binary to /usr/bin?  by default, the "vim" path is /usr/bin/vim.  If you compile from source, you'll likely need to either copy the vim binary to /usr/bin/vim (thus overwriting the original vim), or launch the compiled version via absolute path (eg. ~/vim-checkout/build/vim).

that's just a guess, however.  I can't see it being anything more than that.

Answer (score 2):

With Homebrew:

```
brew install macvim
ln -s /usr/local/bin/mvim /usr/local/bin/vim
```

Answer (score 1):

Can also symlink your new binary to /usr/local/bin/